# Typecasting nested methods using the dot operator in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angularfire2

So I am looking to get type checking in my VScode editor on a nested property. I am using AngularFire and want to apply the `CollectionReference` to the output of the `ref` property in the following.

This is the full statement

`this.db.collection('collections').ref.doc().id`

The above, if broken into multiple lines as shown below works fine and I get code completion.

```
 let temp : CollectionReference;
 temp=this.db.collection('collections').ref;
 console.log(temp.doc().id);
```

How can I convert this into a one-line statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
(<CollectionReference>this.db.collection('collections').ref).doc().id
```

Comment: this works an alternative is `(this.db.collection('collections').ref as CollectionReference).doc().id`